# Magento 2 Customers not displayed in admin grid

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, magento2.3.4

When a customer registers, the details are loaded to the database and the customer is able to login and do the purchases. But in the Customer -> All Customers I am not seeing any registered customers. Please help. I have attached the screenshots in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zso9M.jpg).

Comment: Please run the "php bin/magento indexer:reindex" command

Comment: yeah,i did it many times still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your **customer_grid** is not indexing properly. Run the following commands in the root of your magento folder.

```
bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid
```

Then run the indexer:reindex on customer_grid again

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Finally clear the cache

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Run customer_grid indexer , but if you have your cron running on server then you don't need to run it manually.